# Listbox inside Expander view in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit, expander

Can we have a list box inside a expander view in wp7. I have a scenario where the listbox items should be added automatically. like.

I have a sample cs code to provide the itemsource and bind the data with the list box.

Cs code:

```
lstsample.Add(new sample() { fname = "3i", lname = "infotech" });
lstsample.Add(new sample() { fname = "Tata", lname = "Consultancy" });
lstsample.Add(new sample() { fname = "Robert", lname = "Bosche" });
lst.ItemsSource=lstsample;
```

can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can write this using ListBox as ItemTemplate in ExpanderView. But why? For what?

Comment: i ve a list of countries and i need to show inside in expander view.

Comment: can u tell me how the xaml should be if using item template